# How can I get the logs of a crashed service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose to up a service. It crashes (I guess since it is supposed to run a server).

I tried

```
docker compose -f [my_docker_compose_file] logs
```

but it doesn't say anything and shouldn't but I can't work around an other way to get the logs.

Question is, how do I retrieve the logs of the crashed service ?

Comment: share the contents of your compose file if you can - to help accelerate help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List out all containers on your machine

```
docker container ls -a
```

The `-a` flag here is important - to include all stopped (e.g., crashed) containers in addition to those still up and running.

Find the container representing your service from this list - suppose it is called `<my-container>`.  To see the logs of this container

```
docker container logs <my-container>
```

Comment: I thought stupidly that I could get the logs from all containers of the service at the same time. Thank you.

Comment: no prob!   we're all continuously learning here.